# ClickOnce Update www Server Link Gives 404 Error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, clickonce

I have a basic C# ClickOnce that I had initially set to update from my local WAMP server and it was working fine. Now I wish to update from an internet server. I have tried Azure web server so provided the address for ClickOnce update location as below:

https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/app-name-folder/myapp.application

But I kept on getting error:

```
+ Downloading https://www.mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/app-name-folder/myapp.application did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Then I thought probably it is due to the SSL (https), I then tried to upload the app to another server that used simple "http":

http://www.mywebsite.com/app-name-folder/myapp.application

and I provided the server address in the update URL field for my ClickOnce app. But this has not made any difference and I am still getting the same error.

I have tried by placing the application in the root directory as well as in a subdirectory in my root directory. I hope I am uploading the right file to the update server which is myapp.application, from this directory:
C:\Users\username\Desktop\Deploy\Application Files\myapp_1_0_0_6.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Could you advise where things are going wrong?

Comment: Remove www from "www.mywebsite.azurewebsites.net"

Comment: @CSharpRocks tried that but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, and I am posting the answer in case anyone else experiences the same problem.

Basically the files that need to go on the update server are located in C:\Users\Me\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Release\app.publish and ALL of them, including the Application Files folder, need uploading to the server for your ClickOnce app to detect and perform the update. Below is a screenshot that shows the content app.publish folder.
[Files/folders to go on the update server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMoFu.png)